# Can I route through interface instead of IP?

Tags: route

I know I can route to another computer by setting its IP as the gateway. Can I also do this by just specifying the interface the packets should take. Like instead of doing `route add gw`, if I say `route add -net X dev interface`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The reason is that there can be any number of hosts connected to that interface, how is your machine supposed to know which one the traffic should be routed through?

If you only want to send a small subset of traffic through the designated host, and not all traffic, yes, you can do that.

```
ip route add 1.2.3.0/24 via 192.168.0.123 dev eth1
```

This will send all traffic destinted to `1.2.3.0/24` through `192.168.0.123` which is connected to `eth1`.

Comment: 'The reason is that there can be any number of hosts connected to that interface'.. sorry i didn't understand this part. to one interface, can't there be just one host connected?

Comment: Yes, it is possible there can be only one host connected, but your machine doesn't know that. It is impossible to determine how many hosts are on your network (the broadcast domain).

Comment: @Stephen: No. Suppose an ethernet cable, lodged in your eth0 NIC, goes to a switch or hub: then your computer is obviously simultaneously connected to several pcs... not just to the one at the other end of the cable.